# How do I install and run TnT (Trigrams 'n' Tags) in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, execute-command

I downloaded the [TnT Part-of-Speech Tagger](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/~thorsten/publications/Brants-TR-TnT.pdf) and want to use it on Ubuntu. I have been following the instructions in the [manual](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/~thorsten/publications/Brants-TR-TnT.pdf) (setting the path, environment variables) however when I finally type a command in shell, say **tnt-para *option filename***, I get the error "**tnt-para: command not found**".

What could be the cause for this? Is there anything else I need to do apart from the first steps: changing path and environment variable?

**Also, for reference**

[image: Outputs as requested by @dessert in the comments]

**edit 2** Upon changes- the ouput is

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH:~/Desktop/components-tnt/tnt/"
TNT_MODELS="~/Desktop/components-tnt/tnt/models/"
```

Comment: Did you do `PATH=$PATH:/your/path/to/tnt && export PATH` and `TNT_MODELS=/your/path/to/tnt/models && export TNT_MODELS`?

Comment: These settings won't survive a reboot, for that you need to enter these lines in your `~/.profile`. Then reboot or do `source ~/.profile` in the terminal where you want to start `tnt` from.

Comment: @dessert Thank you for the help. I did follow the above steps, both temporary and permanent- however it now gives the error, tnt-para: command not found

Comment: Please add the outputs of the following commands to your question: `echo $PATH` and `cat ~/.profile | sed -e '/#/d' -e '/^$/d'`

Comment: @dessert Please find the edit above

Comment: You entered the path incorrectly and therefore the system can't find the files. In your `.profile`, change it to `~/Desktop/components-tnt/tnt/` in the `PATH` variable and to `~/Desktop/components-tnt/tnt/models/` in the `TNT_MODELS` variable, then save the file, run `source ~/.profile` and try `tnt-para` again.

Comment: @dessert I get the output: tnt-para - no such file or directory :(

Comment: Did you enter the paths exactly like I wrote? Please do `cat ~/.profile | sed -e '/#/d' -e '/^$/d'` again, copy the output into your question, mark them and press the `{}` button.

Comment: @dessert done! please find above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64242/discussion-between-dessert-and-soumya-singh).